# How to scan for networks in the area

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a question; I want to be able to make an iPhone iOS 5 app which can scan for networks and afterwords and prefereable filter one out [on SSID, for example], and show this in a list

I am looking for a class than can handle this but Im finding a lot of classes that handles services in a network.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you check out the WWDC videos which are free from Apple about Bonjour. Alternatively, just check out using Bonjour.  It's probably the best internet network interface known to man.

Comment: Bonjour is for looking services in the network where your already connected to and not to new networks..